# confused value scope in python

Tags: python

Hi  I have staring programming with c and I conld'nt understand value scope in python.

here is my code

```
class ScenarioEnvironment():
    def __init__(self):
        print(self)

class report():
    config = ScenarioEnvironment()
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ScenarioEnvironment()
```

what happens passing config and config at init()?

and I wonder the value scope which config will be class valuable?

Comment: You aren't passing config into the report class, and this won't run because you are missing a parameter to the other class constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the differences between class attribute and instance object attribute.
Maybe these codes will help you:

```
class TestConfig1(object):
    config = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = 2


class TestConfig2(object):
    config = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.config2 = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print TestConfig1.config
    t = TestConfig1()
    print t.config
    t2 = TestConfig2()
    print t2.config
    print t2.config2
```

more you can see the python blog.[click here](http://www.cnblogs.com/worldisimple/archive/2012/04/20/2460632.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems a bit ambiguous, I'll just comment/fix your code:

```
class ScenarioEnvironment():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x  # Assigning instance variable x to constructor parameter x.
        print(self)  # You're printing the object instance.

class report():
    # Static variable shared amongst all classes.
    config = ScenarioEnvironment(None)  # Assigned to new instance of ScenarioEnvironment.

    def __init__(self):
        # No argument, must pass one (None).
        # self.config is to a new ScenarioEnvironment instance.
        self.config = ScenarioEnvironment(None)
```

Lets try out the classes.

**Output:**

```
s = ScenarioEnvironment(None)
r = report()
>>> <__main__.ScenarioEnvironment instance at 0x026F4238>
>>> <__main__.ScenarioEnvironment instance at 0x026F4300>
>>> <__main__.ScenarioEnvironment instance at 0x026F4350>
```